# Different Ways to Call Google Analytics from Server Side?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, measurement-protocol, google-analytics-sdk

Currently, I am using Measurement Protocol to push the data to GA. The problem is I didn't get any response back for Success or Error on Production, If yes Please suggest?
Due to this, I am looking if there is any other options available for the same like can we achieve it using analytics 360?

Answer (score 0):

The google analytics production data collection endpoint does not return a request status back (always 200 OK) by design to ensure ultra-light processing speed.

What I usually recommend to clients using Measurement Protocol server-side is to

1. To log a reasonable amount (or all of them) of requests somewhere. Storage is extremely cheap nowadays and knowing the data format if an emergency happens you will be able to manually extract the data
2. Every once in a while (one on thousand or one on a million or even more oftne depending on the importance of the data randomly) validate request on GA debug endpoint and parse the returned json. If there are any warnings or error send a notification for further investigation. This way, if anything went wrong you will be on top of the problem by the time BI & Marketing Team would be affected